# Can I only plot errorbar except the point in gnuplot?

Tags: plot, gnuplot, errorbar

The error bar looks strange. when I remove the point.

I think this is because the error value is very small

I just want to see the red error bar. How can I do?[image][image][image]

```
1 set term postscrip eps color
2 set output "result.eps"
3
4
5 set errorbars linecolor rgb "red" linewidth 1
6 plot "sigma.dat" using 1:2:3:4 with errorbars pointtype 0, \
7      "sigma.dat" using 1:2 with lines
```

Comment: How small are your error values? I cannot (yer) reproduce your graph. Please provide the data! Which gnuplot version and operating system are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate question (sort of)
[White background in gnuplot data points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77344492/white-background-in-gnuplot-data-points)

`set pointintervalbox 0`